# Associated record is nil in integration test after saving in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a controller I have an `update` method which creates a record (call it `book`), associates it to an existing record (call it `author`) and saves it.

`Book` belongs to one `Author`

**add_author_to_book_controller.rb**

```rb
def update
  @author = App::Models::Author.new(params)
  @book = App::Models::Book.where(id: params[:book_id]).first
  @book.author = @author
  @book.save!
  # this works fine...
  # puts @book.author.inspect 
  render json: { status: :ok }
end
```

**add_author_to_book_controller_spec.rb**

```rb
describe App::AddAuthorToBookController do
  describe '#update' do
    # this is a contrived example, there is more setup regarding creating the "book" properly...
    let(:name) { 'foobar' }
    let(:action) { xhr :put, :update, params }
    let(:params) { { first_name: name } }
    subject { book }
    before { action }

    it { expect(response.status).to eq 200 }
    it 'should save the author to the book' do
      # why is author nil here?
      # puts book.author.inspect
      expect(book.author.first_name).to eq name
    end
  end
end
```

I tried `book.reload` in the test but that didn't work. I'm new to rails, is there some conventional way of testing an associated record in a controller test?

Comment: are you providing `book_id` in the test request? Is it returning 200 status?

Comment: @maxpleaner yep, the controller returns the correct status and in the controller `puts` is logging the correct relationship. right now i'm trying to actually refetch `book` from mongo in the test after it has been saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't saving `author` before associating it to `book`...

```rb
def update
  @author = App::Models::Author.new(params)
  # was simply missing this
  @author.save!
  @book = App::Models::Book.where(id: params[:book_id]).first
  @book.author = @author
  @book.save!
  # this works fine...
  # puts @book.author.inspect 
  render json: { status: :ok }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to make your controllers more general because that is the correct architecture you need to follow, so your controller can be called `authors_controller.rb` and manage all authors stuff or `books_controller.rb` and manage all books stuff. And following this approach you can have a method `associate_book` which receives an author and a book and creates the right association. Let me explain it with code:

```rb
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  # Fields :name
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Book < AoplicationRecord
  # Optional because I think you want to add the author after create it
  belongs_to :author, optional: true
  # Fields :title, :publish_year, :author_id
  validates :title, :publish_year, :author_id, presence: true
end

class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def associate_book
    # params here will contain the following [:author_id, book_id]
    author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
    book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    book.author = author
    book.save!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => error
    # This will allow you to catch exceptions related to the update
  end
end
```

Then you can test this method by doing the following, supposing that this method will be called from a route

```rb
# Testing with RSpec
# spec/controllers/authors_controller.rb
RSpec.describe AuthorsController do
  let(:author) { Author.first }
  let(:book) { Book.first }
  it 'Should associate an author with a provided book' do
    expect do
      post :associate_book, params: { author_id: author.id, book_id: book.id }
    end.to change { author.books.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

This will check the total count of books associated to the author.